# How to get rid of excess vertices lined up in a straight line

Tags: modeling

I have a cube that is subdivided and with a hole cut through it, but there are 2 excess vertices on each edge between the real vertices. How do i properly delete them without upsetting my project?

EDIT: what to do if the vertex is in the middle of an edge?

[image]

[image]

Comment: please add a screenshot

Comment: my computer is updating one minute

Comment: there i added a pic in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do that in edge mode, dissolve edges around the hole. there will be too edges remaining (causing an error when trying to dissolve)

[image]

then, go in vertex mode, select corner vertices and join them with <kbd>J</kbd>

[image]

Do the same on the other corner, now you can dissolve the 2 remaining edges and the excess vertices.

Comment: at first, you'd better use inset (I) or extrude (E) to create the hole in the face. subdividing like that will lead to problems.

Comment: check my post, i have one more question!

Comment: as said in the answer, dissolve edges. if vertex alone, dissolve vertice, if problem occurs, join the vertice to another and dissolve the edge.

Comment: and what do i do with those two new edges?

Comment: nothing, you can't delete or dissolve them. but you won't have excess vertices anymore.

Comment: Ok well why, after filling the hole, do those two edges still not delete?

Comment: you can join the face if there's no hole in it.

Comment: and dissolve vertices/edges remaining.

Answer (score 4):

Someonewithpc's answer is almost right. The correct operator for this purpose is located in the same menu, it's the *Limited Dissolve*. It allows to limit the max angle, so setting the value low enough will remove only the excess vertices on straight edges.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the *Dissolve* operator for this. Select the edges that contain the vertices to be dissolved, by going into Edge Select mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>>*Edge*), and press <kbd>X</kbd>>*Dissolve Vertices*. This will delete all "unneeded" vertices, so that the shape of the object doesn't change; it will, however, create n-gons, which are not good in some cases.

[image]

In this specific case, this you can't select the entire face and dissolve it, because there must always be edges that connect the outer to the inner part of the front face, as an n-gon cannot have a hole.

Comment: That is actually not true. The Dissolve Vertices will remove all vertices, not only the unneeded ones. For example, it will also remove the corner vertices even if they are connected to other edges.